# Releasing packages with bloom, what can go in the "doc" field?

Tags: ros, ros2, documentation, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running `bloom-release` on a repository I'm trying to release, bloom asks for a link to the documentation.
Upon inspection of [distribution.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/galactic/distribution.yaml), it seems that most maintainers just have a link to their project github repo.

In my project, I am writing up my user guide with ReadTheDocs. I think the simplicity of RTD is great for writing up a user guide that doesn't have to explicitly refer to parts of the code.

Now, is it appropriate to use a link, such as https://soccer-interfaces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, in the doc field of the bloom-release? Or does it have to be a ros wiki page?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383108/releasing-packages-with-bloom,-what-can-go-in-the-%22doc%22-field?/) by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2021-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-24**:
The information Bloom asks for is not necessarily a "link to the documentation". It asks for the *source* repository which could contain documentation (ie: in addition to source code). In most cases, that will be the repository containing the C++/Python/whatever sources for your package, as that would result in automatic builds of API documentation and some other things.

For the ROS 1 side of this (and perhaps to clarify what Bloom is asking for), see [Indexing Your ROS Repository for Documentation Generation](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Refer to @gvdhoorn 's comment for details:

> Bloom is asking for the *source* repository which could contain documentation

So, a user manual hosted on RTD shouldn't be in the "doc" field.

---

Originally posted by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) with karma: 460 on 2021-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0